# KeyError Django rest framework

Tags: python, django

I am receiving KeyError from the application. I have a field `patientName` in my model, however, the problem raised is related to `patientName`. Can anyone please help with this, I have been struggling with this for a few days.
I am not very sure if I made a mistake here. I wanted to use filter, to receive only the `patientName`, `patientNRIC`, and `patientAddress`, however, it fails.

The error msg:

```
KeyError at /patient/
'patientName'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/patient/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'patientName'
Exception Location: D:\Code_Enviroment\Visual_Code_Env\project\myproject\api_basic\views.py, line 19, in patient_list
Python Executable:  D:\python\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\Code_Enviroment\\Visual_Code_Env\\project\\myproject',
 'D:\\python\\python39.zip',
 'D:\\python\\DLLs',
 'D:\\python\\lib',
 'D:\\python',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'D:\\python\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 22 Apr 2021 08:01:39 +0000
```

view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import PatientDetail
from .serializer import PatientSerializer
import sqlite3

# Create your views here.


@api_view(['Get', 'POST'])
# @csrf_exempt  
def patient_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':    
        data = request.data
        patientname = data['patientName']
        # patientnric = data['patientNRIC']

        patientdetails = PatientDetail.objects.filter(patientName = patientname )
        # patientdetails = PatientDetail.objects.all()
        # serialization
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patientdetails, many=True)
        # return Json
        return Response(serializer.data)

        

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        #data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PatientSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['Get', 'PUT','DELETE'])
@csrf_exempt
def patient_detail(request,patientNRIC):
    try:
        patientdetails = PatientDetail.objects.get(patientNRIC = patientNRIC)

    except PatientDetail.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == "GET":

        # serialization, getting one data only
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patientdetails)
        # return Json
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "PUT":
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PatientSerializer(patientdetails, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        patientdetails.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models




class PatientDetail(models.Model):

    patientName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patientNRIC = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    patientAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patientAllergies = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    patientMedicationName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dosage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sideEffects = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patientName
```

Comment: can you post the complete traceback please?

Comment: added the error msg

Comment: can you check the request with print(reques.Data) ? it seems like no key with name "patienName" in your request

Comment: I tried return Response(request.data). It returns an list

Comment: returns an empty list

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are not passing any request data in the request body, hence `KeyError` has been triggered.

`request.data` will have data when you use `POST` method to send data, since you are using `GET` method, your request body will be empty. Also, you should use parameters to pass in data if you are using `GET` method like `<url-endpoint>/?patientName=John` and fetch it by using `request.query_params['patientName']`.

Comment: could you elaborate more on that, i am a bit confused actually.Thank you.